# Exception occurred while flushing email queue on Ionos virtual cloud server

Tags: smtp, swiftmailer

I have a Symfony 4 application running on 1und1 on a package called "1&1 Unlimited Plus". The SMTP config looks like this:

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.1and1.com?username=****&password=******
```

and it works fine. I also have a development copy of this application on my local dev server with same config. This dev copy can send emails, too.

Since the databases on "1&1 Unlimited Plus" are limited to 1GB, I ordered another cloud server from Ionos. With the same config I am not able to send emails. I got this error in dev.log:

```
Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Connection could not be established with host smtp.1and1.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

Ping on smtp.1and1.com works, it reveals the same IP like if I ping on my dev server. On this cloud server I have running:

- Plesk Onyx
- Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS‬
- DNS turned off. I have just an A-record on the origin server to the IP of cloud server. NO MX-records set.
- I checked the firewall rules. No outgoing limits found, just incoming. I added TCP 25 to incoming rules but I dont know if it is necessary.

I tried another ports but then I got this:

```
Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 220 but got an empty response []
```

More config:

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Ionos closes the outgoing port 25 per default. This is nothing I can find or change in admin area, only technical support can open this port.